# Android java.net.DatagramSocket EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, sony

I tried to Connect my Sony Camera to an App.
To get the Device Information I first need to send 3 times a packet and then wait for the Response. Code looks like the SDK sample:

```
int SSDP_MX = 1;
int SSDP_PORT = 1900;
String SSDP_ADDR = "239.255.255.250";

String ssdpRequest =
      "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" + String.format("HOST: %s:%d\r\n", SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
      + String.format("MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n")
      + String.format("MX: %d\r\n", SSDP_MX)
      + String.format("ST: %s\r\n", SSDP_ST) + "\r\n";
                    
socket = new DatagramSocket();
InetSocketAddress iAddress = new InetSocketAddress(SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT);
packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, iAddress);
// send 3 times
socket.send(packet);
Thread.sleep(100);
socket.send(packet);
Thread.sleep(100);
socket.send(packet);
```

My Problem now is that sometime it works multiple times perfectly and another time `EPERM (Operation not permitted)` occurs. When this happens nothing works anymore. Even after reinstalling the App, stopping it, rebooting the Smartphone, the Error occurs all the time.
Stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:603)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:571)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:124)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:721)
    at com.sonyAdvancedRemote.kilian.api.camera.CameraDeviceSearcher$1.run(CameraDeviceSearcher.java:137)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    at libcore.io.Linux.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Linux.sendto(Linux.java:227)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:304)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:569)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:124) 
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:721) 
    at com.sonyAdvancedRemote.kilian.api.camera.CameraDeviceSearcher$1.run(CameraDeviceSearcher.java:137)
```

The Original Sony Play Memories Apps seems to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` where it executes a `Runnable` which sends the Data. Also it uses `MulticastSocket` but I didn't completely understand the code to rebuild it, anyway I think my Problem will still remain because I already tried to use a Multicast socket.

Any idea how I can fix it?

**Edit 1**

So I'd take a deeper look into the code of the official PlayMemoriesApp.

```
socket = new MulticastSocket(1900);
mMcInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ADD);
socket.joinGroup(mMcInetAddress);
                        
 packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, iAddress);
                   socket.setNetworkInterface( NetworkInterface.getByName("interfaceName"));
 Runnable sendTask = () -> {
         try {
              socket.send(packet);
              receiveReplyPackets();
                        };
         try {
               this.mScheduledExecutor.execute(sendTask);
               this.mScheduledExecutor.schedule(sendTask, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
               this.mScheduledExecutor.schedule(sendTask, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

My idea there was to try all different network interface, because I was not 100% sure which one they use. I ended up testing all 25. Sometimes I could send it but I got no response from the server, or I get the `Operation permitted` error.

**Solution**

After some research I found this project: https://github.com/praetoriandroid/sony-camera-remote-java/blob/master/sony-camera-remote-lib/src/main/java/com/praetoriandroid/cameraremote/SsdpClient.java

What's different there, is that he's using another socketaddress:

```
SocketAddress localAddress = new InetSocketAddress(getFirstWiFiAddress(), 0);
socket = new DatagramSocket(localAddress);

private InetAddress getFirstWiFiAddress() {
        String WIFI_INTERFACE_NAME = "^w.*[0-9]$";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces;
            for (interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); interfaces.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
                if (!networkInterface.getName().matches(WIFI_INTERFACE_NAME)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses;
                for (inetAddresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses(); inetAddresses.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress address = inetAddresses.nextElement();
                    if (!address.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (address instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        return address;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ignored) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```